# Change the title font type in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have a custom font already uploaded as Qfont and I would like to apply it to the title of a PlotWidget.I managed to apply it to the tick axis labels but I had no luck so far with the title itself. This is how I managed for the axis:

```
import pyqtgraph as pq
from PyQt5 import QtGui
id = QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(cnst.ABS_FONT_PATH + 'Century18th.ttf')
_fontstr = QtGui.QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(id)[0]
font= QtGui.QFont(_fontstr, 40)

....

widg = pq.PlotWidget(background=(0, 0, 0, 255), x=[0, 1, 2, 3], y=[0, 1, 2, 3],font= font,font_size= 30) 
item= widg.getPlotItem()
item.getAxis("bottom").tickFont = font
item.getAxis("left").tickFont = font
```

is there something similar to tickFont for the Title? Setting the font parameter at the PlotWidget initialization doesn't change things for me...

Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I figured out a way to do this by looking in both the pyqtgraph and pyqt API details.

```
...
widg = pq.PlotWidget(background=(0, 0, 0, 255), x=[0, 1, 2, 3], 
                             y=[0, 1, 2, 3],font= font,font_size= 30) 
item= widg.getPlotItem()
item.titleLabel.item.setFont(font)
```

PS: There may be more elegant direct ways in the future if they expand the pyqtgraph API (current solution works for vs 0.10.0). Feel free to comment if you have found a smarter way :)

Comment: Hi there, could you let me know how to set the font for axis label in pyqtgraph

Comment: hello guys, is there any ways to set title font size if i use GraphicsLayoutWidget?